# Calling AsyncTask with context from Activity and Service

Tags: java, android, android-context

I have `AsyncTask` in which I'm using to download files and display `ProgressDialog` while downloading.

```
public class DownloadFiles extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {

    private final ProgressDialog mDialog;


    public DownloadFiles(Context context, String path1 String path2,
            Long id ) {

        mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        mDialog.setMax(100);
        mDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mDialog.setProgress(0);
        mDialog.show();

    }
```

When I call it from `Activity` it works good, but I have a `Service` that should use this 
`DownloadFiles` to download files and display `ProgressDialog`.

The problem is when I call it :

```
Intent service = new Intent(this,DownloadFiles.class);
startService(service);
```

It have problems to initialising it with `content` from `Service` and get crash on line:

```
mDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
```

How can I run it from my `Activity` and From `Service`?

Answer (score 0):

Take a quick look at [this link](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/) under `Context Capabilities`. It will explain you that a Service context can't display a Dialog.
Instead, you could for example display a Notification when you're running the AsyncTask from a Service, and a ProgressDialog when you run it from an Activity.

Comment: I see... cant I 'fake' it somehow? In my AsyncTask I'm using an ProgressDialog that API forcing me to init.

Comment: No, if you try to display a Dialog from a Service, the System will crash your app.